# Can we count on C structs well behaved format?

Tags: c, gcc

Can we predict how a C struct will be implemented by the compiler?

If I write the (very badly aligned) struct:

```
struct {
  uint16_t a;
  uint32_t b;
  uint8_t c;
} s;

char *p = (char*)&s;
```

can I guarantee that `p[6]` is the same as `s.c`? Are the struct fields allocated in this most obvious and canonical way, so we can predict where each field will be in memory?

Edit: Will `struct __attribute__ ((__packed__)) {...} s;` get me this behavior in GCC?

Comment: If you find yourself needing to do this, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @R. Probably, but not necessarily. I've used something like this at times. For one example, it will let you treat a number of struct elements as if they were an array of T. For example, a struct containing 5 strings that you'd *like* to print out in a loop instead of having printing each separately.

Comment: Of course, when I did it, I used `offsetof`, as advised in my answer -- that gives portable code, as long as you do it correctly.

Comment: @Jerry: Note that OP wants bad alignment/packing, which is somewhat different from your example. I would go so far as to say any code with `__attribute__((packed))` or equivalent is doing things the wrong way.

Comment: @R. Sorry, I thought you meant that wanting the offset(s) of members was wrong. `__attribute__((packed))` is a whole different story, and I completely agree that it's almost certainly a bad idea (though based on which answer was accepted, you're undoubtedly correct that it's what the OP was asking about).

Comment: Maybe he's mirroring a struct to a binary format in a file. That is the only legitimate reason I know to set byte packing.

Comment: Actually I am bound to a network protocol, and using the packed struct gives me good way to represent the messages inside the code. Isn't it a fair use?

Comment: Yes, equiv. to the file example I gave. Don't forget about byte order.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No you cannot. Don't do that.

You are guaranteed only the order and the same compiler will always do the same layout.

If you need such a thing consult your compiler's documentation for how to enable byte packing (always available) and pad yourself.

Comment: The same exact version of the compiler with the same command line options.

Comment: Uhh command lines won't matter unless the change which version of the standard library is being linked with.

Comment: On *most* platforms struct layout rules are part of the ABI.

Comment: @Joshura - the packing might be different between release/debug builds

Answer (score 7):

The fields have to be allocated in ascending order, but the compiler is free to insert padding between fields as it sees fit, so there's no guarantee of what value of `n` in `p[n]` will refer to `s.c`. OTOH, you *can* obtain the correct offset using `offsetof(s,c)`.

Comment: `#include <stddef.h>` for that!

Answer (score 2):

Even with the `__packed__` attribute, it may be impossible to get this alignment due to architectural restrictions. For example, if `uint32_t` requires 4-byte alignment, it will be at offset 4 even with `__packed__`.

If you need to assume a particular alignment, put in a static check that will prevent the code compiling with a different alignment.

Comment: Huh? I'm told the compiler will generate the necessary instructions to read an unaligned integer into memory in that case.

Answer (score 1):

For a given version of a compiler on a given version of the operating system - and with the same build options = yes

But don't !

Answer (score 0):

See `#pragma pack(packed)` and `#pragma pack(reset)`. It has the same impact as the GCC attribute `__packed__` you mentioned.